# execute php/javascript function after a certain amount of time has passed

Tags: php, jquery, time

I need to be able to execute either a php or jquery function to update a sql database every certain segment of time, 20 minutes for example, regardless of user activity on the website. Does anyone know the easiest way to do this? Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make a PHP script that does the update, then use a CRON Job to run it every 20 minutes.

Comment: thanks for the quick responses guys, I've used a cron before on my own server, but i recently bought hosting on bluehost, can run cronjobs on my hosting like that?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for a [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on *nix (or "Scheduled Tasks" on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Use a cron job that executes a php page:

```
wget http://www...com/cron.php
```

Put your database update script in `cron.php`

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution but you have to have access to command line.
But for information: You can make a php engine. So make a infinite loop while(true), inside use a sleep function and make the proper updates.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, on bluehost I just go to cronjobs and input the path to the php script, it worked great, thanks